# Error when creating an Oracle connection from Pentaho Kettle 8.0.0.0-28

Tags: pentaho

I need to connect to an Oracle database from the Spoon and adding all the data requested to create the connection, when making the TEST, it always tells me that the usr / passwd is incorrect, when in fact all data is OK. I have an Oracle Database 12c installed, download the JAR file: ojdbc7 and add it in the path: ... \ data-integration \ lib

Attached screen with connection settings

[image]

This is the error message

```
Error connecting to database [Desarrollo Oracle] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver) ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver) ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2782)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:607)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:47)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:118)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:60)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:494)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:481)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.newConnection(Spoon.java:8750)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1366)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7984)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9245)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:692)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver) ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:588)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
... 57 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:938)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:480)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:416)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:825)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:596)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:585)
... 58 more
Hostname :10.10.10.10 Port :1521 Database name :DESA
```

thank you very much

Comment: It might be possible that issue with jar file, I don’t work with oracle but you can take a latest jar file version and check whether it is working or not.

Comment: Hi Matt,
Try with ojdc6.jar, ojdbc7.jar and with ojdbc8.jar and the error is the same.
I have the JDK8 version installed.
What else could it be?
Thank you.

Comment: Go with Jdk 10 and try... ideally it has not to make much difference but still you can try.

Comment: With JDK10, PDI does not respond, it remains in the main screen and then I must force its closure.

Comment: Install PDI 7.1 and with PDI 8.1 and the error is the same, so now I ask. What files are necessary to connect to a DB ORacle 12.1.0.2 from PDI? Someone knows?

Answer (score 3):

Solved! When having a DB 12c, it is not necessary to put in the SID of the DB, it is necessary to put in the connection the name of the PDB before putting an "/" and with that connects of correct way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnmID.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GByaS.png)